# Copy a file to folder from another folder using JSP

Tags: jsp, filestream

As Title asks how to copy a file from folder to folder using jsp.This can be achieved by JAVA.but same concept in JSP throws error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: strict servlet API: cannot call getOutputStream() after getWriter()
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.getOutputStream(ServletResponseImpl.java:281)
    at iims.filter.MutableHttpResponse.writeContent(MutableHttpResponse.java:106)
    at iims.filter.MutableHttpResponse.write(MutableHttpResponse.java:99)
    at iims.filter.IIMSRestrictDirectURLAccessFilter.doFilter(IIMSRestrictDirectURLAccessFilter.java:293)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The JSP code follows:

```
<%
     File src = new File("C:/bea/user_projects/domains/OICDomain/DOC_SERVER/REPORT_HTML_DUMP/"+strFile);
     String p = src.getName();
     File dest = new File("C:/bea/user_projects/domains/OICDomain/applications/IIMS/IIMS/target/source/REPORT_HTML_DUMP/"+p);           
      dest.createNewFile();
      logHandle.log("Copying files from" +src+ "to" +dest);  

            InputStream inin = new FileInputStream(src);
            OutputStream inout = new FileOutputStream(dest);     
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes 
                while ((length = inin.read(buffer)) > 0){
                        inout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                        }
                logHandle.log("Copied Successfully");
            inin.close();
            inout.flush();
            inout.close(); 
    %>
```

Please resolve this issue.

Comment: I have checked above code, and its successfully copy the file from folder to folder , can you please mention servlet code?

Comment: why don't you use some other java bean to do that ?

Comment: @Zealous no servlet is mapped to this JSP..

Comment: @RevathiMuthukrishnan : Do you have any other java code in current jsp file ? if it has then post that code. As per the error there should be some code which calls getWriter() and getOutputStream() methods on response object.